# To simplify the series of matrices

Tags: matrices, power-series, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be a square matrix in the form $A=B+O(h^2)$, where $B$ is a fixed matrix, and $O(h^2)$ is a matrix with very small elements. Assume that: $$(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2+A^3+...$$
How can I esimate the right hand side of the equality above ? Is that right $(I-B)^{-1}+O(h^2) ?$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=B-K$, where $K$ is a small variable matrix. Then, by the Taylor's formula $(I-A)^{-1}=(I-B+K)^{-1}=(I-B)^{-1}-(I-B)^{-1}K(I-B)^{-1}+O(||K||^2)$. If $||K||=O(h^2)$, then $||(I-B)^{-1}K(I-B)^{-1}||=O(h^2)$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *the below answer is incorrect - the binomial theorem doesn't apply because $O(h^2)$ doesn't necessarily commute past $B$.*

A rather slapdash (*i.e.* non-rigourous) way of doing it is just to substitute $A = B + O(h^2)$ in the right-hand side, and notice that by the binomial theorem we have $$(B+O(h^2))^n = B^n +nO(h^2)B^{n-1} = B^n + O(h^2)$$

This gives you $I + B + B^2 + \ldots + O(h^2) = (I-B)^{-1} + O(h^2)$, as you say.

Comment: Are you sure that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nO(h^2)B^{n-1}=O(h^2)$?

Comment: No! I meant "slapdash" when I said it. You have that $(1-A)^{-1}$ converges, but you don't even necessarily know $(1-B)^{-1}$ converges (except for sufficiently small $h$), for example. If you wanted to be rigorous about it you would want to put extra conditions on $B$.

As an example, $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ will behave spectacularly badly! The answer holds for "sufficiently nice" $B$.

Comment: Thank you. I'll think more about this. Do you have nay ideas about the conditions of matrix $B$ so that the right hand side of above expression can be expressed in the form $(I-B)^{-1}+O(h^2)$?

Comment: Actually, I've just realised my answer is complete rubbish, I'm sorry - I was thinking of $O(h^2)$ as a real-valued function, not a matrix. To apply the binomial theorem as I have done requires $O(h)^2$ to commute past $B$.